Mainstream movie from over 40 years ago of interracial cuckold scene
I'm trying to find a movie that I watched as a teen in either the late 60's or early 70's with the following scene. A husband and wife are alone, he is in living room reading newspaper, she is in bedroom. She is sexually frustrated and is asking for him to come join her. He ignores her and continues to read newspaper. Escaped convicts invade their home and the husband is tied up in his chair. One of the convicts, an African American, goes in the room with the wife. The husband begins to hear noises from bedroom and thinks his wife is being raped, when in fact she is enjoying the encounter. 
The movie aired anywhere from 1968 to 1972 and was a US movie with English as the language. The only other detail I remember is that there was 3 escaped convicts in the movie.
Any ideas on the title of this movie? I have no idea of any of the starts. I watched it at a drive in which probably makes it a B movie. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Welcome to Movies & TV! Please try to add anything that may help identification. What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

The movie aired anywhere from 1968 to 1972 and was a US movie with English as the language. The only other detail I remember is that there was 3 escaped convicts in the movie.

Straw Dogs (the Dustin Hoffman version) definitely had a controversial "she's enjoying being raped" type scene, but I'm not sure if the perpetrator was black. [EDIT] Just found the scene on YouTube and he's not black.

@Darren -- not a lot of black people in rural Cornwall in the 1960's.

Could it be The Defiant Ones?  A pair of criminals, one black, one white.
From IMDb:

Two escaped convicts chained together, white and black, must learn to get along in order to elude capture.





Thanks. I believe Delinquent Schoolgirls is the movie with the scene I was looking for.

@Daveycrocket76 -- does a sexploitation movie like that count as  "mainstream"?  Delinquent Schoolgirls (also called Carnal Madness, Delinquent College Girls, The Delinquents, Love Maniacs, and, supposedly, The Sizzlers Scrubbers 2) starred as the black escapee, stuntman Bob Minor, who also doubled for Sidney Poitier, who starred in The Defiant Ones.  The other two inmates were Stephen Stucker ("And Leon's getting laaaarger!" from Airplane) and Michael Pataki, who is  the first person to ever speak Klingon, playing Korax in the Star Trek episode, "The Trouble With Tribbles".

@Daveycrocket76: If Delinquent Schoolgirls is indeed the movie, can you accept it as the answer? Thanks!

Yes, I can accept it as the answer. Thanks everyone.

@Daveycrocket76: To officially accept the answer, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. Thanks!

There is one more thing I need help with on this movie. I have tried to find it to buy it on amazon and imbd. No luck so far. Anybody know where I could buy it at a reasonable price?

@Daveycrocket76 If this is the match then it's preferable to accept the answer and you can even upvote it.
